# Demat & Trading account will reduce Cibil score?

Tags: india, credit-score, credit, credit-report, credit-history

I have opened Trading Demat Account before 2 years. But i used only 2 months. Will it reduce cibil score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demat account does not impact your score.

Trading account will impact only if you have taken margin and not paid, unlikely for retail accounts.

Having trading and demat account and not using does not impact CIBIL score.

Comment: Like that i have another doubt. When i work in my old office, I gave my PAN number for my senior to fill IT. Is it any problem for cibil score?